# DOM 4 Polyfills vs. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, polyfills

Recently, I've been doing more and more JavaScript code without the help of jQuery. jQuery is great, sure, but with modern browsers (down to and including IE 8) it's not a big deal to write plain JS.

However, jQuery's syntax is simply better. And now, I've stumbled upon a DOM 4 polyfill library: https://github.com/WebReflection/dom4

DOM 4 supports lots of DOM methods that are very similar to jQuery (e.g. $.prepend, $.append, $.parent, etc.). And the polyfills are rather small in size (some 10 kB). So my question is: Is it a good idea to use DOM 4 polyfills and write really modern JS, or is there any catch?

Comment: It's not going to be as widely tested as `jQuery` so it's less reliable on paper. But the web isn't black magic. Use it and see how it works for you. If you can run it on all your target browsers then what else do you need?

Comment: That's one point, yes: the library and its cousins are not widely used, yet. Another question is: How likely will those methods get included in modern browsers.

Comment: What do you mean by included in modern browsers? For instance, `jQuery` is not included in the browser. That's why `jQuery` exists, so that people like us can add functionality to our web application.

Comment: Included, well, rather *supported*. E.g. Chrome and Firefox currently support .closest() and .matches()/.matchesSelector(). IE doesn't. With these methods, jQuery becomes obsolete. And despite I love jQuery to overcome browser issues, it's not that important any more and it adds significant overhead to a web page.